# Why does GitHub recommend https over ssh urls?

Tags: git, github, protocols

I just noticed that the [**GitHub** Help](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) is recommending `HTTPS` over `SSH` URLs

Why is this? GitHub originally recommended using `SSH` but they now recommend `HTTPS` to access and update repositories?

Comment: Maybe GitHub can tell you?  I'm unclear of any clear advantage of HTTPS with SSH cloning right off the bat, save for the simpler approach it gives you when you want to manage more than a handful of repositories without private keys to any of them.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink it's very interesting information! thanks

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink's link provides a more thorough helpful comparison than the [GitHub Help page](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does GitHub recommend HTTPS over SSH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041729/why-does-github-recommend-https-over-ssh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [link provided by @Jonathan.Brink](https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747), the main advantages motivating [GitHub's recommendation of `HTTPS` over `SSH` URLs](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) is that

1. it typically works in places where SSH and plain-Git protocols get blocked (and can sometimes be faster)
2. it allows for [two-factor authentication using a personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/)
3. it will always verify the server (though this may not be as secure as one would hope)