# Are there any reasons to not use SSH as a Git transport?

Tags: git, ssh

I've been trying to set up Gitblit on a local server and getting HTTPS to work without disabling SSL verification in the local client - which I don't want to do.

I've therefore been looking at cloning from Gitblit via SSH and I was wondering if there are any disadvantages in doing so, or if it simply doesn't make any difference?

Comment: Related questions :http://serverfault.com/questions/430059/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-ssh-and-http-for-a-git-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041729/why-does-github-recommend-https-vs-ssh