# Not able to push on git : Permission denied

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Initially my git was logged in to abc@gmail.com
Later I want to push my new code to repository to email xyz@gmail.com

Trying to push my android code on github.

All the steps are going fine. Now when last when I do this :

```
git push origin master
```

It shows :

```
remote: Permission to ****/******.git denied to xyz@gmail.com.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/*********/ScanFiles.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

But when I do : `git config --global user.email`
It shows `xyc@gmail.com`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have both emails listed on your profile on github?

Comment: yes, also my repository is created perfectly on github

Comment: have you found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't care what you put in the user name and email address fields.  You can call yourself whatever you like.  When you run `git push`, though, you have your Git call up some other Git on some other computer or web site—some other machine, anyway, and that other *machine* requires that you authenticate yourself *to that machine* before that machine will run *its* Git.

It's this step—the authentication of yourself as yourself—that is failing.  Git is not yet involved!  Once you solve that problem, *then* you can worry about whether the *Git* on that system believes you when you claim to be Barack Obama or whoever; that's a separate issue.

Since you are using GitHub, you may wish to start with [GitHub's help page on authentication](https://help.github.com/categories/authenticating-to-github/).  You might also read [this answer on credential helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/1256452) and [Why does GitHub recommend HTTPS over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041729/1256452) (which notes that GitHub themselves have waffled over whether to prefer ssh or https).